# Enviar GET en el consumo de API (Problemas con cabeceras)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, curl

Hola estoy consumiendo una API desde Postman y me retorna bien pero al escribir el código en C# siempre me retorna error 406.

Como podría solucionar esto?

Este es el código que genera el postman:

```
curl --location 'https://gw-sandbox-qa.apps.ambientesbc.com/public-partner/sb/v1/operations/product-specific/consumer-services/brokered-product/bancolombiapay-wallet-syncing/terms/retrieveTerms' \
--header 'accept: application/vnd.bancolombia.v4+json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'messageId: 1511a409-ecaa-4d96-baee-eca3380b2ee0' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer AAIgMzFlNjU0ZWJjZGUzMmI4NmNkNTVlNDYxOTQyYzQ4MDJKh3L2o2vVpEOAOb0lAucUyEmjrvpRCTfjm0U1LKJnNToRiVa2FmDMEeuRKG5SplFk_EAR12bf-QdkKzp4795qA7e_M42dgSUHZEAiMTPX7Jcr9M1B1Xa0BFYCbjRo6mKAA3-ZLT9WzREXKj3IdAUI' \
--header 'Cookie: incap_ses_9084_2772063=5U98cSi4gxyfuO7s89kQfgjHEWUAAAAAUmWCV+bhXPQhRkk7GeXQkw==; nlbi_2772063=F1j/aGBJzjwetYC54mx6zAAAAAB41KAs9j9NnYuvEaUMgXuh; visid_incap_2772063=IrJBP/zwTu2oebwS+WwJIb8pA2UAAAAAQUIPAAAAAADgAKQPRMxcamQNhA1cz4Hz'
```

Este es mi código C#

```
public  async Task RetrieveTermsAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var objauth = await GetTokenAccess();
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Configurar los encabezados requeridos
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.bancolombia.v4+json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("messageid", "1511a409-ecaa-4d96-baee-eca3380b2ee0");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", objauth.Access_Token);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.bancolombia.v4+json");

            // Realizar la solicitud GET
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://gw-sandbox-qa.apps.ambientesbc.com/public-partner/sb/v1/operations/product-specific/consumer-services/brokered-product/bancolombiapay-wallet-syncing/terms/retrieveTerms");

                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        var error = ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probaste con `messageId` con la `I` mayúscula, en `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("messageid", "1511a409...` ?

Comment: Si , lo probe messageId    
Yussef